# calculate time to response in lotus notes messages

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

We are working with Lotus Notes in a Help Desk team and would be useful to know how much time we take to respond a message. Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the software called http://timetoreply.com which measures how quickly companies respond to online enquiries. You can measure email reply time using this software and its free.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the suggested approaches, is that they only measure the amount of time until someone begins to compose a response -- not the time until the response is sent. This, you could determine by forcing the replies to automatically save so that an agent could go through later to compare the received of original messages with the sent of the replies.

HOWEVER! As an occasional user of support services, I *really* don't want support staff measured on how quickly they respond. That's not a true measure of customer perceived value. I would instead want my support staff measured on how long it is before the customer feels their problem has been solved. Quality of service comes about from taking the trouble to understand the customer's question and carefully address their needs -- not from churning out reply emails at the fastest possible pace, which is what the proposed measurement would encourage.

I don't want a tech scored higher for replying immediately with a stupid non-answer, then replying immediately to my irritated request that they read the question, with another non-answer, than a tech who takes twice as long to send the original reply, but that reply answers my question. See?

Comment: Hi Andre! Thanks for the answer. My scenario demand this kind of control, we need to know how much time the help desk team takes to respond for demand managing purposes. The quality of service will be a next step. I´ll try the suggestions and give feeback in this post.

Comment: I think Andre is very correct, a quick response is useless if it does not actually help the user. I also sometimes need to use help desks, and often get a very quick response, but it is a canned response that does not address my question...
I understand that you have been asked by some managers to do this, and it is not your choice. However, you COULD give them back a dose of their own medicine. :-)  Write some code quickly, say in 5 minutes, that does not do anything. It can just print "Hello World". But you did deliver the code in 5 minutes. That it was useless shouldn't matter to them. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a field that will record timestamp when the mail was replied to, ie. when user clicks on reply button, set the field's value to current time, then do the calculation of time passed between @created and that timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course there is. If you have a current mail template, then responding to a mail sets a flag in the document. That changes the @Modified timestamp of the document. 
A view with a column that calculates @Modified - @Created could already be a good start. Of course you can add any level of complexity to this by using LotusScript or Formula agents to analyze your data or to add own flags, etc...

Comment: Flagging the message (and probably other things) also updates the @Modified stamp, so I don't think that alone would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi Torsten! It worked on a way, but i guess the formula calculate the move of a message to another folder too, for example. There´s is a way to achieve only the response time? Thanks!

Comment: Richard is right: EVERY change in the document (though move to another folder is NOT a change) will change @Modified... if you really want to make SURE, that only responding time is measured, then there has to be coding in the Reply- Actions, that sets a timestamp... Just a view lines of code, but not to easy to do it right, as it means changing in the mailfile / mail template and has to be done right...